# Particular value from a string using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I need to extract the $value from the given piece of string .

```
string text = "<h2 class="knownclass unknownclass1 unknownclass2" title="Example title>$Value </h2>"
```

Using the code -:

```
Match m2 = Regex.Match(text, @"<h2 class=""knownclass(.*)</h2>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It gets me the full value -: unknownclass1 unknownclass2" title="Example title>$Value .But I just need the $value part.
Please tell me .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this string **always** adhere to this format?

Comment: Your text is XML, seems to me it would be far easier, faster, and more clear to parse it into an XElement instance and then pull out value of the element.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string always follows this format, consider the following code:

```
var index = text.IndexOf(">");
text.Substring(index + 1, text.IndexOf("<", index));
```

Answer (score 0):

As had been said multiple time, using a Regex for parsing HTML or XML is bad. Ignoring that, you are capturing too much. Here is an alternative Regex that should work.

```
@"<h2 class=""knownclass[^""]*"">(.*)</h2>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If its always the same pattern of your string, you can consider this:

```
string text = "<h2 class=\"knownclass unknownclass1 unknownclass2\" title=\"Example title>$Value </h2>";
string result = "";

Regex test = new Regex(@"\<.*?\>(.*?)\</h2\>");
MatchCollection matchlist = test.Matches(text);

if (matchlist.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matchlist.Count; i++)
    {
        result = matchlist[i].Groups[1].ToString();
    }
}
```

But if you are working with XML files or HTML files, I recommend you use XmlTextReader for XML and HtmlAgilityPack for HTML

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

hope it helps!

Comment: Yes it will do ,thanks a lot .Can you please tell what to do if there are some unknown spaces between the character ">" and $value.Eg.            <h2 .....>     $value     </h2> Thanks. :)

Comment: I tried it found the solution Regex test = new Regex(@"\<.*?\>\s*(.*?)\</h2\>"); Thank you!